# What signal is sent to running process after network fail?

Tags: networking, unix, kill

I am trying to reproduce a situation where a process fails due to a network outage. I was hoping to reproduce this signal with a kill command. A normal kill command is not working. I have taken a look at /usr/include/sys/signal.h to try to find a signal that refers to anything that might be related to a network outage, but with no luck. Has anybody tried to reproduce a network outage with the kill command?

Sorry if this is a newbish question! Please correct me if I am going about this in a completely wrong way.

Comment: [Windmills do not work that way!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) (in other words, "Yes, you're going about this in a completely wrong way" - look into alternate kinds of IPC, like dbus)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None. A "network failure" is not a signal.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, signals dont work that way, they are not generally tied to specific error codes like "no network", I assume you are coming from a Windows background?  If you want to reproduce a network failure, cause it by having the process try to access a non existent address or by disabling the network link temporarily on the test machine.